# Add a ToolTip to Data GridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

How can I add a Tooltip to Data GridView in C# using Visual Studio 2012?

I want to put it in the header cells
I don't see any place in HeaderStyle.

how can i do that?

Comment: If you want a more specific answer for your situation, please include some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Specific cell**

You can add a tooltip to the `DataGridViewCell`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tooltiptext(v=vs.110).aspx

Use the CellFormatting event as demonstrated on MSDN:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if ( (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Rating"].Index)
        && e.Value != null )
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = 
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (e.Value.Equals("*"))
        {                
            cell.ToolTipText = "very bad";
        }
        else if (e.Value.Equals("**"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "bad";
        }
        else if (e.Value.Equals("***"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "good";
        }
        else if (e.Value.Equals("****"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "very good";
        }
    }
}
```

You may have to set the `ShowCellToolTips` property on the datatable to `true`;

**Entire row**

If you want to set a tooltip on the entire header row then use something like this:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // I assumed the header row was the first row, that explains the check for 0, change it if needed.
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.Index == 0)
    {
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Header tooltip";
         //or (e.g. for web)
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("title", "Header tooltip");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `Column` has a Property `HeaderCell` of type `DataGridViewHeaderCell`.

You can set its `ToolTipText`  like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndexOrName].HeaderCell.ToolTipText = "OK";
```